# INSERT INTO Syntax Error, works on Access

Tags: c#, database, insert

This just throws up a syntax error. Tried to fix this by adding and removing quotation marks etc. Help <3

```
OleDbCommand register = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO userList (Username, Password) VALUES (@user, @pass);", connection);
        register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
        register.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox2.Text);
        OleDbCommand checkUsed = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Username FROM userList WHERE Username=@user", connection);
        checkUsed.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBox1.Text);
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = checkUsed.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username taken!");
        } else
        {
            register.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Please tell us what database you are using, and include the “syntax error” in your question.

Comment: you cannot execute `register` as the connection has an open DataReader. nothing to do with a syntax error, though

Answer (score 1):

turns out Password is a protected keyword in access or what ever. Changing it to Pass worked fine ;).

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark without knowing what type of database you're using, but it might not support the VALUES keyword, in which case this might work instead:

```
INSERT INTO userList (Username, Password) SELECT @user, @pass;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need a close bracket ")" after the parameters in the "register" command.